# Uniform convergence on different intervals

Tags: uniform-convergence

Compute $\|f_n\|_E\quad$ for $\quad f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\quad$ where  $\quad E=[0,1],\quad$ and $\quad E=[1,\infty].\quad$ In which case does $f_n$ converge uniformly to $0$?

Below are my calculations for the interval $[0,1]$-

For $x=0, \quad f_n(0)=0.\quad$For $x>0,\quad$ $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$
$\quad\implies\quad f_n(x)\longrightarrow 0 \ $ pointwise for each $x>0.$

Now $$\|f_n\|_{[0,1]}= \sup\{|f_n(x)|;0 \leq x \leq1\}.$$

We have $$f_n(x)-f(x)=f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}.$$

As $$\quad \frac{d}{dx}\bigg[\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}\bigg]=\frac{n-n^3x^2}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}=0\quad \text{when}\quad x=\frac{1}{n}$$

Thus$$\|f_n-f\|_{[0,1]}=\bigg|f_n\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)-f\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)\bigg|=\frac{1}{2}\quad\implies\quad\text{not uniformly convergent}. $$

Is this correct? And assuming it is correct I do not see how the result would be different for the interval $[1,\infty],$ but the solutions manual states that the interval $[1,\infty]$ is uniformly convergent on this interval.What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards the interval $[0,1]$ you are correct. Looking back to your calculations
$$f'_n(x)=\frac{n(1-(nx)^2)}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}<0\quad \mbox{for $x>1/n$},$$
that is $f_n$ is decreasing (and positive) in the interval $[1,+\infty)$. Hence
$$\|f_n\|_{[1,+\infty]}= f_n(1)=\frac{n}{1+n^2}\to 0$$
and the sequence $(f_n)_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f=0$ in $[1,+\infty)$. Note that the maximum point $1/n$ belongs to $[0,1]$ and not to $[1,+\infty)$ for $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I am (slowly) starting to grasp it but I do not follow the last sentence that the maximum belongs to one interval but not the other. Appreciate it you could elaborate on that part.

Comment: Scrub that last comment I think it clicked. For values of x between 0 and 1 the maximum is located at 1/n. But for values of x between 1 and infinity fn is decreasing so the only max is at fn(1). Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Great! Thank you Robert!

Comment: You are welcome!